# Free software to convert MP3 files to M4B on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, conversion, mp3, m4b

I'm seeking free software that would convert a bunch of MP3 files into one M4B file (audio book) that:

- works on Windows XP
- needs no additional tools to be installed
- can mark the chapters.

So far I tried "[Chapter and Verse](http://lodensoftware.com/chapter-and-verse/)" but it cannot start up (there's an error message saying "Chapter and Verse.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close"), as its latest update is 1 year ago, I guess better forget it.
Also seems it requires Apple QuickTime to be installed to run.

I also tried [MP3 to iPod Audio Book Converter](http://mp3-to-ipod-audio-book-converter.en.softonic.com/),
but it cannot config the chapters' names.

There's also another link on this forum [How to convert series of MP3 to a M4B in a batch](https://superuser.com/questions/56961/how-to-convert-series-of-mp3-to-a-m4b-in-a-batch), but it seems talks about Mac, not Windows, and I don't quite understand, it talks about ffmpeg, on my Windows XP I can't find it.

Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last link you quoted seems to answer the question, and especially the part by @evilsoup:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:input0.mp3|input1.mp3|input2.mp3" -c libfdk_aac -b 64k output.m4b
```

Ffmpeg is a third-party product and is not a standard part of Windows.
You need to download and install ffmpeg from its [website](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Ffmpeg is normally self-sufficient and does not require additional installations,
but as evilsoup remarks, different flavors of ffmpeg may have different libraries
included. You will have to try and see if the result is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is FOSS application which you can download from there build [site](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), and then you can run the command you saw @ https://superuser.com/a/521939/305250