# ffmpeg consolidating multiple mp3 files into 1 m4b file

Tags: audio, conversion, mp3, audiobook, m4b

I chose ffmpeg as the tool by recommendation from [How to convert series of MP3 to a M4B in a batch](https://superuser.com/questions/56961/how-to-convert-series-of-mp3-to-a-m4b-in-a-batch) .

I downloaded the static build for windows from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ .

When I try to combine 4 mp3 files into 1 m4b file, the error happened as below. what shall I do? by right ffmpeg support  m4b files....

I ran:

```
C:\EBC>ffmpeg -i "concat:65.mp3|airbus.mp3|alcoholabuse.mp3|allergies.mp3" -c libfdk_aac -b:a 64k EBC.m4b
```

Error:

```
ffmpeg version N-66564-gc29d999 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers   built on Oct  2 2014 00:53:44 with gcc 4.9.1 (GCC)   configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3
--disable-w32threads --enable-av isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca -- enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
--enable-libvorbis  --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable- libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib   libavutil      54.  7.101 / 54.  7.101   libavcodec     56.  1.102 / 56.  1.102   libavformat    56.  7.102 / 56.  7.102   libavdevice    56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100   libavfilter     5.  1.102 /  5.  1.102   libswscale      3.  1.100 / 
3.  1.100   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100   libpostproc    53.  1.100 / 53.  1.100 [mp3 @ 02dca020] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate Input #0, mp3, from 'concat:65.mp3|airbus.mp3|alcoholabuse.mp3|allergies.mp3':   Metadata:
    album_artist    : British Council
    title           : When I'm 65
    artist          : British Council
    album           : British Council
    encoded_by      : MPH
    genre           : Podcast
    copyright       : British Council
    date            : 2006   Duration: 00:10:42.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 160 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 250x250 [SAR 100:100 DAR 1 :1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           :
      comment         : Cover (front) [NULL @ 02dc7480] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'EBC.m4b' EBC.m4b: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.m4b` isn't recognized by ffmpeg.

Two solutions:

- use `-f mp4` to force MP4 format output, or
- use `.m4a` as file name and rename them later manually

Comment: Is m4a compatible to m4b?

Comment: It's the exact same file format (MPEG-4 Part 14), just a different file ending, to make it clear that it's an audio book rather than a video (`.m4v`) or a plain audio file (`.m4a`).

Comment: @K7AAY Please post a new question including the full command line and the entire command line output that you got.

Comment: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30740/ffmpeg-concatenation-of-mp3-files-to-single-m4a-file-fails/30744#30744